# Using pd.Series.str.contains to find if an string exists in a column

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, series, contains

I am trying to find whether a string is equal to one of the values in an existing pandas Dataframe, using the `.str.contains()` function. I have defined a simple dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Name', 'Attr', 'Description'])
df = df.append({'Name':'Water'}, ignore_index=True)
```

In a separate for loop, I was going through a list of strings and checking if any were contained in the dataframe:

`print(df["Name"].str.contains(i[0].text))`

Now, I purposefully gave `df` an element with 'Water' as the name because it existed in this list of strings, but the above line returned all `False` values.

I then tried `print(df["Name"].str.contains(df["Name"][0]))` as a sanity check, but even this returned `False`.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I verified that `.str.contains` works on a simple string such as 'a', but it is not detecting equivalent strings.

Comment: I am getting `True` for `print(df["Name"].str.contains(df["Name"][0]))`

Comment: I tried the same example given by you, it returned true for me.